# Multiple Elseif Statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I am attempting to create a function looking like this:

```
region <- function(State){
region_vector <- 
    ifelse(State %in% c("CT", "DE", "DC", "MD", "ME", "MD", "MA", "NH","NJ", "NY", "PA", "RI", "VT"), "Northeast",
    ifelse(State %in% c("IN", "KY", "MI", "OH", "PA", "WV") "East Central", 
    ifelse(State %in% c("IN", "KY", "MI", "OH", "PA", "WV") "East Central", 
    ifelse(State %in% c("CO", "IL", "IA", "KS", "MN", "MO", "MT", "NE", "ND", "SD", "WI", "WY") "West Central",  
    ifelse(State %in% c("AL", "FL", "GA", "MS", "NC", "SC", "TN", "VA") "Southeast",
    ifelse(State %in% c("AR", "LA", "NM", "OK", "TC") "Southwest", 
    ifelse(State %in% c("AK", "AZ", "CA", "HI", "ID", "NV", "OR", "UT", "WA") "Pacific",
           "NA" )))))))
return(region_vector)  }
```

I would like to assign regions to a column in my data that looks like
`c ("CA", "NY", "CO"...)` What is wrong with the code I've written above? The error message is `unexpected string constant in c (...)`

Comment: This looks like a good case for `switch`. Look up `?switch`. As for your error, you're missing commas between the c(...) and What you want to replace the contents of c(...) with. Also, don't know about you, but too many ifelse can land you in nest of trouble!

Comment: `switch`? No, you need a lookup table and then do a `merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for show you other way to do this and how slooow `ifelse` is, some examples :

```
# Lookup list
l <- list(
  "Northeast" = c("CT", "DE", "DC", "MD", "ME", "MA", "NH","NJ", "NY", "RI", "VT"),
  "East central" = c("IN", "KY", "MI", "OH", "PA", "WV"),
  "West central" = c("CO", "IL", "IA", "KS", "MN", "MO", "MT", "NE", "ND", "SD", "WI", "WY"),
  "Southeast" = c("AL", "FL", "GA", "MS", "NC", "SC", "TN", "VA"),
  "Southwest" = c("AR", "LA", "NM", "OK", "TC"),
  "Pacific" = c("AK", "AZ", "CA", "HI", "ID", "NV", "OR", "UT", "WA")
)
# long list
L <- unlist(l)
names(L) <- rep(names(l), times = lapply(l, length))
# data.frame
df <- data.frame(
  CODE = unlist(l),
  LABEL = rep(names(l), times = lapply(l, length)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL
)

# Test data
set.seed(123)
test <- data.frame(CODE = sample(x = unlist(l), size = 1e4, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Fun to recode with match
match_recode <- function(var, dico) {
  names(dico)[match(x = var, table = dico)]
}

# With ifelse
region <- function(State){
  region_vector <- 
    ifelse(State %in% c("CT", "DE", "DC", "MD", "ME", "MA", "NH","NJ", "NY", "RI", "VT"), "Northeast",
           ifelse(State %in% c("IN", "KY", "MI", "OH", "PA", "WV"), "East Central", 
                  ifelse(State %in% c("IN", "KY", "MI", "OH", "PA", "WV"), "East Central", 
                         ifelse(State %in% c("CO", "IL", "IA", "KS", "MN", "MO", "MT", "NE", "ND", "SD", "WI", "WY"), "West Central",  
                                ifelse(State %in% c("AL", "FL", "GA", "MS", "NC", "SC", "TN", "VA"), "Southeast",
                                       ifelse(State %in% c("AR", "LA", "NM", "OK", "TC"), "Southwest", 
                                              ifelse(State %in% c("AK", "AZ", "CA", "HI", "ID", "NV", "OR", "UT", "WA"), "Pacific",
                                                     "NA" )))))))
  return(region_vector)  
}

# With data.table
dt_recode <- function(var, dico) {
  dt <- data.table(CODE = var)
  setkey(dt, CODE)
  dt <- dt[dico]
  return(dt$LABEL)
}
```

Test results

```
table(match_recode(test$CODE, dico = L))
# East central    Northeast      Pacific    Southeast    Southwest West central 
#         1211         2132         1711         1554          998         2394 
table(region(test$CODE))
# East central    Northeast      Pacific    Southeast    Southwest West central 
#         1211         2132         1711         1554          998         2394 
library("data.table")
table(dt_recode(test$CODE, dico = df))
# East central    Northeast      Pacific    Southeast    Southwest West central 
#         1211         2132         1711         1554          998         2394 

# All the same
```

Benchmark :

```
library("microbenchmark")
microbenchmark(match_recode(test$CODE, dico = L), 
               region(test$CODE),
               dt_recode(test$CODE, dico = df), 
               times = 100L)
# Unit: microseconds
#                              expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
# match_recode(test$CODE, dico = L)   266.845   271.549   344.7044   288.2265   298.7035  1138.792   100
# region(test$CODE)                 23454.496 24250.325 26391.6468 24637.9750 25257.4050 49958.884   100
# dt_recode(test$CODE, dico = df)    1133.233  1184.977  1355.1031  1364.3705  1445.8345  2116.794   100
```

`match` is much more faster than `ifelse` !

There's probably a better way with `data.table`

PS : in yours `ifelse`, `MD` appears twice in Northeast, `PA` is both in Northeast and in East Central